# Load several files into HIVE table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

Look I'm trying to analyze too many files into just one HIVE table. Key insights, I'm working with json files and the tables structure is :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test1
(
STATIONS ARRAY<STRING>,
SCHEMESUSPENDED STRING,
TIMELOAD TIMESTAMP
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION '/user/andres/hive/bixihistorical/';
```

I need to load around 50 files with the same structure all of them. I have tried things like:

```
LOAD DATA  INPATH '/user/andres/datasets/bixi2017/*.json'
OVERWRITE INTO TABLE test1;

LOAD DATA  INPATH '/user/andres/datasets/bixi2017/*'
OVERWRITE INTO TABLE test1;

LOAD DATA  INPATH '/user/andres/datasets/bixi2017/'
OVERWRITE INTO TABLE test1;
```

Any of those above have worked, any idea guys about how should I go thru?
thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so so .... Well, I just remember that you can create just an external table stored in the same folder all files with the same structure are located. So , in that way I will load whole records in one shoot.

```
> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE bixi_his
> (
> STATIONS ARRAY<STRUCT<id: INT,s:STRING,n:string,st:string,b:string,su:string,m:string,lu:string,lc:string,bk:string,bl:string,la:float,lo:float,da:int,dx:int,ba:int,bx:int>>,
> SCHEMESUSPENDED STRING,
> TIMELOAD BIGINT
> )
> ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
> LOCATION '/user/ingenieroandresangel/datasets/bixi2017/';
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure folder contains only that files which needs to be loaded into Hive table.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test1
(
STATIONS ARRAY<STRING>,
SCHEMESUSPENDED STRING,
TIMELOAD TIMESTAMP
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION '/user/andres/hive/bixihistorical/';


LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/andres/datasets/bixi2017/'
OVERWRITE INTO TABLE test1;
```

Comment: I tried this look at my examples in posting. so what I did was in the create table aim the location to files repository!! thanks